# Adding a mouseClicked function to dictate where the stamp image of the cat will land

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am unsure how to add a mouseClicked function to this code, I have tried giving it a go before asking for help- I have created a mouseClicked function and put in the code from the draw function. I have tried to change the random to mouseX and mouseY to try and change each stamp image from appearing random so you can control the appearance of the sketch by clicking where you want each stamp to go.

here is the code below any tips or help to add the mouseClicked function will be really appreciated as I am still an amateur at coding:

```
let img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('cat.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  img.resize(img.width / 4, img.height / 4);
  
  background(32);
}

function draw() {
  const scalar = .5; 
  const pg = colorize();
  image(pg,
        random(-pg.width, width),
        random(-pg.height, height),
        pg.width * scalar,
        pg.height * scalar);
  pg.remove();
}

function colorize(){
  const pg = createGraphics(img.width, img.height);
  const randomColor = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  
  img.loadPixels();
  for (let y = 0; y < img.height; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < img.width; x++){
      let i = (y * 4) * img.width + x * 4;

      if(img.pixels[i + 3] > 0){    
        pg.set(x, y, randomColor);
      }
    }
  }
  pg.updatePixels();
  return pg;
}
```

i have tried to make mouseX and mouseY as well as mouseClicked new functions with no luck.
here is my attempt:

```
let img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('sillybandz.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  img.resize(img.width / 8, img.height / 8);
  background(50);
  frameRate(60);
}

function draw() {
  const scalar = .5; 
  const pg = colorize();
  // i added another element
  // one image flashing colours in the same place as a center point
  image(pg,
  // middle image loaded will be bigger 
    width / 2 - pg.width / 2,
    height / 2 - pg.height / 2)
    
 image(pg,
        random(-pg.width, width),
        random(-pg.height, height),
        pg.width * scalar,
        pg.height * scalar);
  pg.remove();
}

function colorize(){
  const pg = createGraphics(img.width, img.height);
  const randomColor = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  
  img.loadPixels();
  for (let y = 0; y < img.height; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < img.width; x++){
      let i = (y * 4) * img.width + x * 4;

      if(img.pixels[i + 3] > 0){  
        pg.set(x, y, randomColor);
      }
    }
  }
  pg.updatePixels();
  return pg;
}

// attempted to add a mouse click function
function mouseClicked(){
 image(mouseX, mouseY, 5, 5);
 return false;
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Why weren't they successful?

Comment: Is this browser JS? Or something else?

Comment: I don't see any [`mouseClicked`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseClicked) here in this code. What help do you need to add it? `function mouseClicked() { /* do whatever you want to happen on mouse click */ }`, right? There's an example in the linked docs that shows using `mouseX` and `mouseY` to add an ellipse wherever the mouse was clicked.

Comment: i have tried using mouseClicked function but as it didnt work i took it out of the code above. i put in the same code that is in the draw function into the new mouseClicked function but it hasn't worked. my problem is i am not sure what to put there to make it work as i am a complete amateur.

Comment: `but it hasn't worked`: howso? What's the actual result vs expected result? is there an error message?

Comment: my expected result will be: click the screen and the stamp image of the cat will appear wherever the mouse is clicked, right now i click and the image is not appearing

Comment: Please [edit] the post to show your attempt, otherwise we can't really tell you what you did wrong. As I mentioned, the [docs show a pretty clear example](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseClicked)--all you need to do is replace `ellipse()` with `image()`.

Comment: hi i have included my code, thank you

Comment: You included `mouseClicked()` but it includes `image()`, but you didn't include the definition for `image()`.